# How to map a port in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I want to build a full adder in VHDL and read the result from one of the pins.

```
entity main is
port (foo: out std_logic);
end entity main;
```

Given this code, how do I map `foo` to a real pin on my FPGA?

---

Here are the details of the FPGA I'm using:

- Manufacturer: Xilinx
- Family: Spartan 3e
- Device: XC3S500E
- Package:FT256

Comment: What manufacturer of FPGA are you using?

Comment: @scary_jeff I've updated the question for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xilinx ISE, add your file to the project; it should be automatically set as the top level entity. In the 'Processes' panel (typically near the bottom left), expand 'User Constraints' and double click 'I/O Pin Planning (PlanAhead) - Pre-Synthesis'. This opens the PlanAhead pin planning tool. Using this, you can easily drag your port onto a pin of your device. Saving in this program should create a 'constraints' (.ucf) file. You can also edit this file manually. ISE will use this constraints file when compiling your FPGA.